# IIS 7 file permissions error

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, permissions, configuration

I keep getting the following error:

```
c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd set site /site.name:"WebVTS" /+bindings.[prot
ocol='https',bindingInformation='*:443:webvts.mprinc.com']
ERROR ( message:Configuration error
Filename: redirection.config
Line Number: 0
Description: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
. )
```

I'm trying to add a hostname to an https: site in IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008. I added IUSR read/modify to my web.config file. But can't seem to figure out where and what is redirection.config?

Comment: Did you run the command prompt as administrator?

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: awesome, that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click "Command Prompt" in your task bar or start menu and select the "Run as Administrator" option.

[image: run as]

This will cause your command prompt to be UAC-elevated, and the window title will change to let you know that your prompt has extra oomph:

[image: admin prompt]